# Can i traverse a objects properties with an array of unknown length?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a complex object in typescript that i want to be able to change with a single function (I know how hacky this sounds, but its a hobby project). The function takes a value and a path as a rest-parameter. The path can be of any length.

I want to change the property, but so far I've only come up with solutions that lose the reference to the original object, and as such is not a working solution.

I've tried using both whiles and for loops to iterate over the array and "zooming" in on the property. In each case, they lost the reference to the original object and thus didn't mutate it.
I've tried accessing the object directly, with a known length, and that works but its hardcoded to a length and as such isn't a good solution either. In a desperate case, i could make a function like this for each size I'm expecting (it's somewhat limited) but that hurts my pride.

Example

```
character: Character = {
  characteristics: {
    0: {
      initial: 30,
      advances: 15
    }
    1...
  }
}

this.updateProperty(35, characteristics, 0, initial) //Change characteristics.0.initial to be 35 instead of 30
```

With a for/while loop:

```
 updateProperty(value: string|number,...path: string[]) {
    let scope: Object = this.character;
    for(let p of path) {
      scope = scope[p];
    }
    scope = value;
    console.log(scope);
    console.log(this.character);
  }
```

the scope is updated correctly, but the character is not changed

With direct access (Here of length 3)

```
  updateProperty(value: string|number,...path: string[]) {
    this.character[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = value;
  }
```

Here its updated correctly, but its no longer taking in any length as it will crash if its longer than 3 and break it if shorter than 3

Attempt to access it directly with an array

```
updateProperty(value: string|number,...path: string[]) {
    this.character[path] = value;
  }
```

Gives

```
ERROR in src/app/character.service.ts(27,20): error TS2538: Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Comment: An example of what you are trying to achieve would be nice.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Okay, I have finally undeleted my answer, see if it works for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your direct access works fine for you, you can try something like:

```js
let character = {
  characteristics: {
    0 : {
      initial: 30,
      advances: 15
    }
  }
}

function updateProperty(value,...path) {
    let finalOb, i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length; i ++) {
        let tempOb
        if (finalOb) {
          tempOb = finalOb[path[i]];    
        } else {
          tempOb = character[path[i]];   
        }
        if (tempOb instanceof Array || typeof tempOb !== 'object') {
            break;
        } else {
            finalOb = tempOb;
        }
    }
    finalOb[path[i]] = value;
}

updateProperty(35, 'characteristics', '0', 'initial')
console.log(character)
```

Comment: Holy hell! It works!. I only had to remove the (tempOb instanceof Array) as there was an array. For what purpose did you include it? Since it works excellently without it

Comment: @ChristofferNørbjerg Checking an array was just a precautionary measure in case you had an Array, You see I am stopping one step before the actual key whose value is to be replaced. `typeof []` will also return `object`

Answer (score 0):

```
updateProperty(value: string|number,...path: string[]) {
    let scope: Object = this.character;
    for(let p of path) {
      scope = scope[p];
    }
    scope = value;
    console.log(scope);
    console.log(this.character);
    this.character = scope; //? 
  }
```

Comment: Problem is at this point scope is representing a single value (String / Number) and not the entire character anymore, so it would overwrite the entire object with the single property we were trying to change

Comment: So maybe : `this.character = {...this.character, ...scope} ` this way you override character with the updated properties from scope.